# Ascii to XML Character set conversion

Tags: c#, xml, visual-c++

Is there any classes to convert ascii to xml characterset preferably opensource i will be using this class either in vc++ or C#

My ascii has some printable characters which is not there in xml character set

i just tried to sen a resume which is in ascii character set and i tried to store it in a online crm and i got this error message

javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[50,22]
Message: Character reference "&#x13" is an invalid XML character.]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your Ascii set includes non-printable characters?

Comment: Do you mean like '<' to '&lt;' ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the conversion you're expecting?

Comment: By "xml characterset", do you mean the escape sequences used to introduce some characters within xml (for example &lt; and such) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your text won't have any *printable* characters which aren't available in XML - but it may have some *unprintable* characters which aren't available in XML.

In particular, Unicode values U+0000 to U+001F are invalid *except* for tab. carriage return and line feed. If you really need those other control characters, you'll have to create your own form of escaping for them, and unescape them at the other end.

Comment: My answer gives code on how to handle this if you're interested. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733544/ascii-to-xml-character-set-conversion/9987636#9987636

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with Excel using the OpenXML document creation in C#.
My Excel Export feature would blow-up when building a doc with a bad ASCII character.
Somehow the string data, in my company's database, has funky characters in it.
Even though I used the Microsoft DocumentFormat.OpenXML assembly from their OpenXML SDK 2.0, it still didn't take care of this when assigning string values using their objects.

**The Fix:**

```
t.Text = Regex.Replace(sValue, @"[\x00-\x08]|[\x0B\x0C]|[\x0E-\x19]|[\uD800-\uDFFF]|[\uFFFE\uFFFF]", "?");
```

This cleans up the sValue string by removing the offending characters and replacing them with a question mark.  You could replace with any string or just use an empty string.

The [XML Spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Valid_characters) Allows 0x09 (TAB), 0x0A (LF - Line Feed or NL - New Line), and 0x0D (CR - Carriage Return).  The RegEx above takes care not remove those.

The XML 1.1 Spec allows you to escape some of these characters.
For example: Using &#x03; for 0x03 appears as  in HTML and as <sup>L</sup> in Office documents and notepad.
I use Asp.net and this is automatically taken care of in my GridView, so I do not need to replace these values - but I believe it may be the browser that takes care of it for all I know.

I thought of escaping these values in OpenXML, but when I looked at the output, it showed the excape markup.  So Mike&#x03;TeeVee still shows up as Mike&#x03;TeeVee in Excel instead of something like MikeTeeVee, or Mike<sup>L</sup>TeeVee.  This is why I preferred the Mike?TeeVee approach.

My hunch is this is a bug in the current OpenXML which encodes the allowed XML ASCII characters, but allows the unsupported ASCII characters to slip on through.

**UPDATE:**

I forgot I could look up how these characters are displayed using the "*Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool*" to see inside docs like Excel.
There I found it uses the format: **_*x0000*_**

Remember: XML 1.0 does not support escaping these values, but XML 1.1 does, so if you're using 1.1, then you can use this code to escape them.

Regular XML 1.1 Escaping:

```
t.Text = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\x00-\x08]|[\x0B\x0C]|[\x0E-\x19]|[\uD800-\uDFFF]|[\uFFFE\uFFFF]",
         delegate(Match m)
         {
           return (byte)(m.Value[0]) == 0 //0x00 is not Supported in 1.0 or 1.1
                  ? ""
                  : ("&#x" + string.Format("{0:00}", (byte)(m.Value[0])) + ";");
         });
```

If you're escaping strings for OpenXML, then use this instead:

```
t.Text = Regex.Replace(s, @"[\x00-\x08]|[\x0B\x0C]|[\x0E-\x19]|[\uD800-\uDFFF]|[\uFFFE\uFFFF]",
         delegate(Match m)
         {
           return (byte)(m.Value[0]) == 0 //0x00 is not Supported in 1.0 or 1.1
                  ? ""
                  : ("_x" + string.Format("{0:0000}", (byte)(m.Value[0])) + "_");
         });
```

Answer (score 3):

The character reference `&#x13` is indeed not a [valid XML character](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets). You probably want either `&#xD` or `&#13`.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiousity, I took a few minutes to write a simple routinein C# to pump out a XML string of the 128 ASCII characters, to my surprise, .NET didn't output a  really valid XML document. I guess the way I output the element text wasn't quite right. Anyway here is the code (comments are welcomed):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "us-ascii", ""));
XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement("ASCII");
doc.AppendChild(elem);
byte[] b = new byte[1];
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    b[0] = Convert.ToByte(i);
    XmlElement e = doc.CreateElement("ASCII_" + i.ToString().PadLeft(3,'0'));
    e.InnerText = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
    elem.AppendChild(e);
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.OuterXml);
```

Here is the formatted output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?>
    <ASCII>
    <ASCII_000>&#x0;</ASCII_000>
    <ASCII_001>&#x1;</ASCII_001>
    <ASCII_002>&#x2;</ASCII_002>
    <ASCII_003>&#x3;</ASCII_003>
    <ASCII_004>&#x4;</ASCII_004>
    <ASCII_005>&#x5;</ASCII_005>
    <ASCII_006>&#x6;</ASCII_006>
    <ASCII_007>&#x7;</ASCII_007>
    <ASCII_008>&#x8;</ASCII_008>
    <ASCII_009> </ASCII_009>
    <ASCII_010>
    </ASCII_010>
    <ASCII_011>&#xB;</ASCII_011>
    <ASCII_012>&#xC;</ASCII_012>
    <ASCII_013>
    </ASCII_013>
    <ASCII_014>&#xE;</ASCII_014>
    <ASCII_015>&#xF;</ASCII_015>
    <ASCII_016>&#x10;</ASCII_016>
    <ASCII_017>&#x11;</ASCII_017>
    <ASCII_018>&#x12;</ASCII_018>
    <ASCII_019>&#x13;</ASCII_019>
    <ASCII_020>&#x14;</ASCII_020>
    <ASCII_021>&#x15;</ASCII_021>
    <ASCII_022>&#x16;</ASCII_022>
    <ASCII_023>&#x17;</ASCII_023>
    <ASCII_024>&#x18;</ASCII_024>
    <ASCII_025>&#x19;</ASCII_025>
    <ASCII_026>&#x1A;</ASCII_026>
    <ASCII_027>&#x1B;</ASCII_027>
    <ASCII_028>&#x1C;</ASCII_028>
    <ASCII_029>&#x1D;</ASCII_029>
    <ASCII_030>&#x1E;</ASCII_030>
    <ASCII_031>&#x1F;</ASCII_031>
    <ASCII_032> </ASCII_032>
    <ASCII_033>!</ASCII_033>
    <ASCII_034>"</ASCII_034>
    <ASCII_035>#</ASCII_035>
    <ASCII_036>$</ASCII_036>
    <ASCII_037>%</ASCII_037>
    <ASCII_038>&amp;</ASCII_038>
    <ASCII_039>'</ASCII_039>
    <ASCII_040>(</ASCII_040>
    <ASCII_041>)</ASCII_041>
    <ASCII_042>*</ASCII_042>
    <ASCII_043>+</ASCII_043>
    <ASCII_044>,</ASCII_044>
    <ASCII_045>-</ASCII_045>
    <ASCII_046>.</ASCII_046>
    <ASCII_047>/</ASCII_047>
    <ASCII_048>0</ASCII_048>
    <ASCII_049>1</ASCII_049>
    <ASCII_050>2</ASCII_050>
    <ASCII_051>3</ASCII_051>
    <ASCII_052>4</ASCII_052>
    <ASCII_053>5</ASCII_053>
    <ASCII_054>6</ASCII_054>
    <ASCII_055>7</ASCII_055>
    <ASCII_056>8</ASCII_056>
    <ASCII_057>9</ASCII_057>
    <ASCII_058>:</ASCII_058>
    <ASCII_059>;</ASCII_059>
    <ASCII_060>&lt;</ASCII_060>
    <ASCII_061>=</ASCII_061>
    <ASCII_062>&gt;</ASCII_062>
    <ASCII_063>?</ASCII_063>
    <ASCII_064>@</ASCII_064>
    <ASCII_065>A</ASCII_065>
    <ASCII_066>B</ASCII_066>
    <ASCII_067>C</ASCII_067>
    <ASCII_068>D</ASCII_068>
    <ASCII_069>E</ASCII_069>
    <ASCII_070>F</ASCII_070>
    <ASCII_071>G</ASCII_071>
    <ASCII_072>H</ASCII_072>
    <ASCII_073>I</ASCII_073>
    <ASCII_074>J</ASCII_074>
    <ASCII_075>K</ASCII_075>
    <ASCII_076>L</ASCII_076>
    <ASCII_077>M</ASCII_077>
    <ASCII_078>N</ASCII_078>
    <ASCII_079>O</ASCII_079>
    <ASCII_080>P</ASCII_080>
    <ASCII_081>Q</ASCII_081>
    <ASCII_082>R</ASCII_082>
    <ASCII_083>S</ASCII_083>
    <ASCII_084>T</ASCII_084>
    <ASCII_085>U</ASCII_085>
    <ASCII_086>V</ASCII_086>
    <ASCII_087>W</ASCII_087>
    <ASCII_088>X</ASCII_088>
    <ASCII_089>Y</ASCII_089>
    <ASCII_090>Z</ASCII_090>
    <ASCII_091>[</ASCII_091>
    <ASCII_092>\</ASCII_092>
    <ASCII_093>]</ASCII_093>
    <ASCII_094>^</ASCII_094>
    <ASCII_095>_</ASCII_095>
    <ASCII_096>`</ASCII_096>
    <ASCII_097>a</ASCII_097>
    <ASCII_098>b</ASCII_098>
    <ASCII_099>c</ASCII_099>
    <ASCII_100>d</ASCII_100>
    <ASCII_101>e</ASCII_101>
    <ASCII_102>f</ASCII_102>
    <ASCII_103>g</ASCII_103>
    <ASCII_104>h</ASCII_104>
    <ASCII_105>i</ASCII_105>
    <ASCII_106>j</ASCII_106>
    <ASCII_107>k</ASCII_107>
    <ASCII_108>l</ASCII_108>
    <ASCII_109>m</ASCII_109>
    <ASCII_110>n</ASCII_110>
    <ASCII_111>o</ASCII_111>
    <ASCII_112>p</ASCII_112>
    <ASCII_113>q</ASCII_113>
    <ASCII_114>r</ASCII_114>
    <ASCII_115>s</ASCII_115>
    <ASCII_116>t</ASCII_116>
    <ASCII_117>u</ASCII_117>
    <ASCII_118>v</ASCII_118>
    <ASCII_119>w</ASCII_119>
    <ASCII_120>x</ASCII_120>
    <ASCII_121>y</ASCII_121>
    <ASCII_122>z</ASCII_122>
    <ASCII_123>{</ASCII_123>
    <ASCII_124>|</ASCII_124>
    <ASCII_125>}</ASCII_125>
    <ASCII_126>~</ASCII_126>
    <ASCII_127></ASCII_127>
</ASCII>
```

**Update:**
Added XML decalration with "us-ascii" encoding

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you don't fully understand what a character set is. XML is not a character set, though XML based output does use character sets to encode data.

I'd recommend reading through Joel Spolsky's excellent post [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), then come back and have another go at your question.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need an additional library to do that. From different encodings to embedded binary data, all of that is possible through the common .net library. Can you just give a simple example?